# Apache Spark Start multiple SparkContext instances

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I would like to know how to create multiple *SparkContext* instances in the same application. Right now, the following message pops up: `org.apache.spark.SparkException`

Is it possible to run more than one *SparkContext* instances in the same application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by using the configuration below:

```
spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts=true
```

Reference: [Support multiple SparkContexts in the same JVM](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243)

Comment: @user2602577if you think it helped you please select it by clicking tickmark on left side of my answer.

Comment: What's your use case? Often, this is not the right approach to the problem